# How to get Facebook users list by GPS location

Tags: facebook, api, gps, location

Is there anything in Facebook's api to get a **list of all users sharing the same location**?

For example a bar, a train station, an office building, a concert, etc.
I am sure Facebook has this information, I wonder if they share it through their api.

Comment: No, there are no endpoints for this kind of information.